# How to access FPDI setSourceFile from public Storage facade link

Tags: laravel, fopen, fpdi

I got an error from FPDI setSourceFile. It shows that `fopen()` cannot find file or directory. I tried to access pdf template from database that I saved using Storage facade link, I think it's stored on `/public/storage` directory. Been using some helper like `asset()`, `url()`, and `Storage::disk('public')->path('')`. Still get the error. Any solution?

Comment: Well, have you tried asking the PDF nicely to open up and let you access it? Maybe offer it a cup of coffee or a snack? Jokes aside, have you checked if the file path is correct? Maybe it's playing hide and seek with you.

Comment: What a nice of you, thx for answering. I checked the path before `setSourceFile` function running. I dd it, it was correct, but it was accessing the `/storage` path not `/public`, which as far as I know, the storage path can't have read access or smth.

Comment: Run `php artisan storage:link`.  Once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created, you can create a URL to the files using the `asset` helper.

Comment: Yup, been doing that. Using `asset()` is solving the issue of `setSourceFile`.  I think I've solved it before i post the question. I encountered new error. But for this question context is solved. Thx a lot brother.